Mule 4 Anypoint studio 7.17 - takes a long time to show properties for connectors like HTTP Request
This is not necessarily a programming question but am getting frustrated with Anypoint studio seemingly 'stuck'for a few seconds before it is able to resolve / display properties for components.
I have seen this to occur with noticeable delays for connectors like HTTP request
does this have to do with metada propogation or is that only involved in case of Dataweave ?
how do I 'speeden'up studio to resolve and display the properties quickly ?
Note:
have already tried to play around with Xms and Xmx properties in ini file
Edit1:
Adding some more details : using windows 10 enterprise edition
16 GB RAM , 13 GB Page file , file system has about 57 GB of free space .
Open JDK 1.8.0.321
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
Edit2: clicking on any component does not show properties immediately and takes atleast 10-15 seconds for meatadata to resolve before rendeirng properties


You are not providing useful information to be able to help. Read [ask]. Provide example  configurations, text only. Which operating system and architecture. How much free memory in the system? Version of the JDK used to run Studio? Which memory configurations are you using?

Also try the latest release of Any point Studio. Bug fixes and improvements are not applied to previous versions.

thanks have added some more details about my environment

1GB of heap memory is too little for Studio. Try with 4 or 8GB.

thanks increased XMX to 4 GB but whenever i click on any component in studio it takes a while and at bottom right can see it trying to resolve metadata :  added image as edit2

Which architecture is your system? 32 bits or 64 bits?

It seems to be something in your environment but it is difficult to say what. It could be an antivirus software or similar.

its 64 bit , what you say about antivirus might be correct , i forget the exact pop up warning but when installing studio , it did ask to exclude some folders from antivurus scan warning that not excluyding would impact performance and since we dont have admin rights we were unable to exclude , so yes probably the antivurus
